# Google Cloud Composer Environment Setup Error: Connect to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create an environment in Google Cloud Composer. [Link here](https://console.cloud.google.com/composer)

When creating the environment from scratch and selecting all the default fields, the following error appears:

```
CREATE operation on this environment failed 22 hours ago with the following error message:
CREATE operation failed. Composer Agent failed with: Cloud Storage Assertions Failed: Unable to write to GCS bucket.
GCS bucket write check failed.
```

I then created a [google cloud storage bucket](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/) within the same project to see if that would help and the same error still appears.

Has anyone been able successfully create a Google Cloud Composer environment and if so please provide guidance on why this error message continues to appear?

Update: Need to update permissions to allow access it seems like. Here is a screenshot of my permissions page but not editable.
[image]

Comment: Have you given permissions to the service account to write to the bucket?

Comment: Permissions should be missing. What are the permissions of your service account?

Comment: @siamsot how do you provide permissions to the service account? Can you share a link/instructions on how to do that?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how do you check your current permissions?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think I found the permissions page but it's not editable (I believe). Am I looking at the wrong section?

Comment: I added a screenshot in the question

Comment: Do you deploy Composer with a custom service account? If not, Does your Cloud Storage set with "Uniform IAM access" mode?

Comment: @guillaume_blaquiere I just use the default service account that auto generates here: service-3742089498@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Looks like based on the account id it has IAM in the name. Does that mean it has Uniform IAM access? If not, can you share where I can check that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't given the required IAM policies to the service account. I would advise you to read more about the IAM policies on Google Cloud [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies)

When it comes to the permissions of the bucket, there are permissions like the [Storage Object Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) that might fit your needs.